# Installing SCL on AWS RHEL 7.6 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, rhel

I’m migrating an internal application to the AWS cloud.

I have created an instance on AWS using the RHEL 7.6 AMI.  One of the things to install is Puppet (server and db).  To have this, we need Ruby 2.5.  Within our organisation, one of the accepted ways to install software that does not come standard with the distribution, is to use SCL.  But I can’t install it, it seems.  When I want to install the optional packages and the scl packages using subscription-manager, nothing can be added.  The list is empty.

What is the standard way to add this to the AWS AMI ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the RHSCL and Optional repos per these [instructions](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world/#fndtn-ruby)?

Comment: Hi Mike.  Seems I totally forgot about this.  I no longer work for this company, so unfortunately I cannot test it anymore.  Sorry for having waited 3 years to come back to this.